# Dynamic Allocation of 2D Array SHARED with mmap

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to map shared memory or allocate it to an existing shared memory using a file association of shared memory using mmap.

The first problem I found was the use of malloc and mmap in `circular_buf_init` function. I think that `malloc` is not shared between processes, and I found the implementation of MAP_ANONYMOUS as a temporary solution.

I am using this struct and its functions:

```c
struct circular_buf_t
{
    char **buffer;
    size_t head;
    size_t tail;
    size_t max; //of the buffer
    bool full;
};

cbuf_handle_t circular_buf_init(cbuf_handle_t cbuf, size_t size)
{
    //cbuf_handle_t cbuf //= malloc(sizeof(circular_buf_t));

    assert(cbuf);
  //size_t cb = sizeof(char *) * size;

  /* cbuf->buffer = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cbuf->buffer[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
  } */

  cbuf->buffer = (char **)mmap(cbuf->buffer, sizeof(char *) * size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cbuf->buffer[i] = (char *)mmap(cbuf->buffer[i], sizeof(char) * 256, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  }

  if (cbuf->buffer == MAP_FAILED)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    cbuf->max = size;
    circular_buf_reset(cbuf);

    assert(circular_buf_empty(cbuf));

  printf("sizeof(cbuf)=%zu\n",sizeof(cbuf));

    return cbuf;
}

void advance_pointer(cbuf_handle_t cbuf)
{

    if (cbuf->full)
    {
        cbuf->tail = (cbuf->tail + 1) % cbuf->max;
    }

    cbuf->head = (cbuf->head + 1) % cbuf->max;

    // We mark full because we will advance tail on the next time around
    cbuf->full = (cbuf->head == cbuf->tail);
}

int circular_buf_put(cbuf_handle_t cbuf, char *data)
{
    int r = -1;

    if (!circular_buf_full(cbuf))
    {
        //cbuf->buffer[cbuf->head] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
        strcpy(cbuf->buffer[cbuf->head], data);
        advance_pointer(cbuf);
        r = 0;
    }

    return r;
}

void print_buffer_status(cbuf_handle_t cbuf)
{
    printf("Full: %d, empty: %d, size: %zu\n",
           circular_buf_full(cbuf),
           circular_buf_empty(cbuf),
           circular_buf_size(cbuf));
}

void circular_buf_reset(cbuf_handle_t cbuf)
{
    cbuf->head = 0;
    cbuf->tail = 0;
    cbuf->full = false;
}

size_t circular_buf_size(cbuf_handle_t cbuf)
{
    size_t size = cbuf->max;

    if (!cbuf->full)
    {
        if (cbuf->head >= cbuf->tail)
        {
            size = (cbuf->head - cbuf->tail);
        }
        else
        {
            size = (cbuf->max + cbuf->head - cbuf->tail);
        }
    }

    return size;
}

size_t circular_buf_capacity(cbuf_handle_t cbuf)
{
    assert(cbuf);

    return cbuf->max;
}



int circular_buf_get(cbuf_handle_t cbuf, char * data)
{
    int r = -1;

    if(!circular_buf_empty(cbuf))
    {
        strcpy(data,cbuf->buffer[cbuf->tail]);
        retreat_pointer(cbuf);

        r = 0;
    }

    return r;
}

bool circular_buf_empty(cbuf_handle_t cbuf)
{
    return (!cbuf->full && (cbuf->head == cbuf->tail));
}

bool circular_buf_full(cbuf_handle_t cbuf)
{
    return cbuf->full;
}
```

In my program

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include "../circular_buffer/circular_buffer.h"
#include "../circular_buffer/circular_buffer.c"
#include "../shared/shared.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int opt, val;
  size_t buffer_size;
  char *buffer_name;

  buffer_size = 0;
  while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:n")) != -1)
  {
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 'n':
      buffer_name = strdup(argv[optind]);
      break;
    case 's':
      buffer_size = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-n buffer_name] [-s buffer_size]\n",
              argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  if (optind >= argc)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument after options\n\tUsage: %s [-n buffer_name] [-s buffer_size]\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("buffer_name argument = %s\n", buffer_name);
  printf("buffer_size argument = %zu\n", buffer_size);
  //create the shared memory segment
  buffer_shm_fd = shm_open(buffer_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
  //configure the size of the shared memory segment
  size_t len = sizeof(struct circular_buf_t); //+ sizeof(char *) * buffer_size * sizeof(char) * 256;
  ftruncate(buffer_shm_fd, len);

  //map the shared memory segment in process address space
  //circular_buf_init(buffer_mem_ptr, buffer_size);

  buffer_mem_ptr = mmap(0, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, buffer_shm_fd, 0);



  circular_buf_init(buffer_mem_ptr, buffer_size);

  printf("sizeof(buffer_mem_ptr) = %zu\n",sizeof(buffer_mem_ptr));
  //printf("cb=%zu\n",cb);
  printf("4096=%zu\n",4096);
  char *s = "datos";
    circular_buf_put(buffer_mem_ptr, s);
    print_buffer_status(buffer_mem_ptr);

  /* char data[256];
            circular_buf_get(buffer_mem_ptr, data);
            printf("%s ", data); */

  //

  if (msync(buffer_mem_ptr, sizeof(buffer_mem_ptr), MS_SYNC) == -1)
    {
        perror("Could not sync the file to disk");
    }


  free(buffer_name);


  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And the second process to use the shared memory is this

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "../shared/shared.h"
#include "../circular_buffer/circular_buffer.h"
#include "../circular_buffer/circular_buffer.c"

int main()
{
  const char *name = "k";
  int shm_fd; //shared memory file discriptor
  int buffer_size = 3;
  size_t len = sizeof(struct circular_buf_t); //+ sizeof(char *) * buffer_size * sizeof(char) * 256;

  /* make * shelf shared between processes*/
  //create the shared memory segment
  shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR, 0666);
  //configure the size of the shared memory segment
  ftruncate(shm_fd, len);
  //map the shared memory segment in process address space
  buffer_mem_ptr = mmap(0, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
  buffer_mem_ptr->buffer = (char **)mmap(buffer_mem_ptr->buffer, sizeof(char *) * buffer_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  for(int i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++){
    buffer_mem_ptr->buffer[i] = (char *)mmap(buffer_mem_ptr->buffer[i], sizeof(char) * 256, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  }

  /* creat/open semaphores*/
  //cook post semaphore fill after cooking a pizza

  print_buffer_status(buffer_mem_ptr);
  printf("\nCook: I have started cooking pizza.\n");


char *s = "datos";
    circular_buf_put(buffer_mem_ptr, s);
    print_buffer_status(buffer_mem_ptr);

    char data[256];
            circular_buf_get(buffer_mem_ptr, data);
            printf("%s ", data);
    /* char *s = "datos";
    circular_buf_get(buffer_mem_ptr, s);
    print_buffer_status(buffer_mem_ptr); */



  return 0;
}
```

But I have no idea how to allocate this dynamic 2d array allocation to shared memory using mmap. Please give me feedback to help find a solution.

Comment: How are you creating the two processes?  Forking and then execing, or forking and running two copies of the original code?  Presumably the latter.  One of the key aspects if you store `char **` in the circular buffer is that the addresses in both processes are the same. That's trivial if you run two copies of the same code — you create the shared memory before you fork. If you have to exec the second program, you can't use MAP_ANON; you have to either use `shm_open()` or `shmget()` — or choose a file to contain the data. And you must ensure that the new process connects with the right address.

Comment: The test `if (optind >= argc)` is usually written `if (optind != argc)`; the error message should be referring to an 'unexpected argument', not an 'expected argument'.

Comment: I updated the use in the second program. I remap the memory in this part `buffer_mem_ptr->buffer = (char **)mmap(buffer_mem_ptr->buffer, sizeof(char *) * buffer_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);`

Comment: Note that POSIX specifies (for [`shm_open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html)): _If name begins with the `<slash>` character, then processes calling `shm_open()` with the same value of name refer to the same shared memory object, as long as that name has not been removed. If name does not begin with the `<slash>` character, the effect is implementation-defined._. If Linux defines what `"k"` means (no leading slash), you'll be OK, but I'd recommend using a name starting with `/` (and not containing more slashes than just that one leading slash).

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, you know many thinks about POSIX and shared memory. I changed my struct with an initialized 2d array `char buffer[4096][256];`. And I followed your recommendations about `shm_open()` (you have good eyes to see it). Maybe to someone else can help this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59232555/4752488. I try to save a 2d array with a struct in file, but it doesn't work.